# Spring MVC won't accept json request body

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

i'm a spring newbie and i'm trying to pass a json object to spring mvc:

**POJO rappresentation of json**

```
public class City implements Serializable{

    private String id;  
    private Map<String,Map<String,String>> translates;
    private Map<String,String> providers;

    public City(){}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getTranslates() {
        return translates;
    }

    public void setTranslates(Map<String, Map<String, String>> translates) {
        this.translates = translates;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getProviders() {
        return providers;
    }

    public void setProviders(Map<String, String> providers) {
        this.providers = providers;
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody City insert(@RequestBody City city){
    return city; // JUST FOR TEST
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-rc2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-rc2</version>
</dependency>
....
```

If i try with that Json

```
{
    "id": "Test",
    "translates": {
        "it": {
            "country": "testCountryIT",
            "city": "testCityIT"
        },
        "en": {
            "country": "testCountryEn",
            "city": "testCityEn"
        }
    },
    "providers": {
        "prov1": "YYY",
        "prov2": "XXX"
    }
}
```

i retrieve that error message:

```
"NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Better question is `what is the problem?`

Comment: oh sorry! see edit please :)

Comment: may u post also the code you use in order to POST the JSON you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you aren't sending the `Content-Type` header with a value of `application/json` in the request. Your request needs to contain that header so that Spring can 1) use the appropriate `HttpMessageConverter` and 2) handle the request with your `@RequestMapping` method.

Comment: Thanks! that was very simple! I add content-type: application/json and it works!!! THANKS!